# Topological "closure" of a binary relation

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $f$ be a binary relation on a set $U$.

Topology $T f = \{ E \in \mathscr{P} U \mid
f [E] \subseteq E \}$ (here $f[E]$ is the image of a set $E$ by binary relation $f$).

**Conjecture** Closure operator $\operatorname{cl}$ of $T f$ is equal to $E \mapsto ( \operatorname{id}_U \cup f \cup
  f^2 \cup f^3 \cup \ldots ) [E]$.

Comment: @CliveNewstead $g\circ f = \{ (x,z) \mid \exists y: (x,y)\in f\land (y,z)\in g \}$. $f^n = f\circ\dots\circ f$ ($n$ times).

Comment: @CliveNewstead Binary relation is a set of pairs, by definition

Comment: Ah ha! Thanks. I need to check my glasses. I guess I assumed it was a function because you called it $f$ ;)

Comment: $E \mapsto ( \operatorname{id}_U \cup f \cup f^2 \cup f^3 \cup \ldots ) [E]$ maps open sets to itself. So, it can be closure only if all open sets are closed. It remains to find a counterexample $f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$E \mapsto ( \operatorname{id}_U \cup f \cup f^2 \cup f^3 \cup \ldots ) [E]$ maps open sets to itself. So, it can be closure only if all open sets are closed.

For a counterexample for the conjecture take $f = \{ (0, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1) \}$. Open sets are $\{ \}$, $\{ 1 \}$, $\{ 0, 1 \}$. $\{ 1 \}$ is open but not closed.